# SQL Server AutoDate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have my server in US and my client is in India, the problem is when he is inserting data there is a autoDate inside MSSql Table, but as the server is in different time zone, We are getting date with 12Hours different, how to overcome it.

Date in Table is AutoDate GetDate()

Regards

Comment: Store the dates in UTC format and while retrieving display based on the time zone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of UTC format may solve your issue. Please refer to these links

- [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/c-convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)
- [How to handle conversion of a DateTime independently of the timezone of the hosting server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5428758)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your default constraint and rely on `GETUTCDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`? This would solve your issue from the storage perspective.

You'd have to slightly alter your html rendering as well, in order to generate the date in a user friendly format, taking into account the user's timezone.